# Bound property not updating upon change

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

In my Blazor app, I have the following input field in a view:

```
<input bind="@amount.Display" type="text" />
```

This is bound to a property defined with the following accessors:

```
get
{
    return _display;
}
set
{
    var parsed = Decimal.Parse(value);
    _display = parsed.ToString("F2");
}
```

The real accessor logic is more complicated than this, but I've simplified it above to the extent that I can while still retaining the behavior that's confusing me.

Basically, when the user enters "2", then tabs or clicks out of the input field, I'd like this to automatically be converted to "2.00". What's strange is that this conversion only seems to happen if the user enters a string representing a number that is different than the one already in place. For example, if the input field currently has a value of "1.00" and I enter "2", I correctly end up with "2.00." But if the input field has a value of "2.00" and I enter "2", it just remains "2". It's as though the set accessor is not being called in this latter case, and I can't imagine why.

Answer (score 12):

The main problem is that Blazor just isn't going to update the textbox if it thinks its value hasn't changed.  Part of this problem with your example is that the internal representation of the value (your property) sometimes doesn't jibe with what you see in the textbox (`2` vs. `2.00`).  But as far as Blazor is concerned if the property value doesn't change it's not going to propagate the binding back to the textbox.

I played around with a number of variants of your code (manually "binding" using `value` and `onchange`) but ultimately if by the time your code finishes updating the value property and the value is the same as it was before, nothing is going to happen.

The only workaround I can think of is to introduce a really ugly hack by using async. When you do this, the event loop completes after the `await` (blazor will accept the new value of `2`), and blazor will again check to see if anything has changed when it resumes the `await` call since at that point it's a new round of the event loop.  Since the new value will now be `2.00` instead of `2` it refreshes the textbox.

```
@functions {
    private string value;

    private string Value
    {
        get => value;
        set => SetValue(value);
    }

    private async void SetValue(string value)
    {
        this.value = value;
        await Task.Delay(1);
        this.value = decimal.Parse(value).ToString("F2");
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

Hopefully someone who knows more about Blazor than me can offer something less atrocious. But it *does* work.  (btw, `Task.Delay(0)` does *not* work, presumably due to some optimization where the task is already complete and so doesn't enlist a promise to get out of the event loop.)

Note:
Once Blazor format strings (i.e. `format-value="yyyy-MM-dd"`) accepts numbers, you will probably be able to simplify this by just storing the value as a decimal and using the format string in razor markup directly.

Comment: As I remark in another comment, it's strange to me that "2" would be considered the same value as "2.00". The input field type is text, not number; and the property in question is a string, not a decimal (you and I know that the string happens to signify a number, but that should be irrelevant). So why shouldn't "2" be considered perfectly well distinct from "2.00"?

Comment: Because Blazor is comparing the value of your _property_.  Let's say you set the textbox to `2` and it gets converted to `2.00` the first time.  The value of your property is the string `2.00`.  Now, let's say you erase that value and put in `2`.  Due to your binding, it sets the value of your property to `2` and your setter overrides that so that the final value is `2.00`.  Blazor sees that the original value (`2.00`) is the same as the new value (`2.00`) and decides there's nothing to do and so the value doesn't update in the textbox.  (it's two-way binding, but it short-circuted)

Comment: Oh, geez, I see it. I suppose the other comments were trying to tell me the same thing and I just didn't get it until now. I may just use some Javascript to format the input in the meantime. Thanks for your help.

Comment: From what you describe, this sounds like a bug in Blazor, because it knows that it called the setter with a different value, yes it was "2.00" before, and it's "2.00" again now -- BUT between those two calls it called the setter with a value of "2", because it was bound to a property -- so it did change, it was "2.00" and "2" and now it's supposed to be "2.00" again... but because Blazor ignores the setter call, it's stuck with a value of "2" being displayed.  This is obviously wrong behavior.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to force UI to re-render, in Blazor I recommend you to use `StateHasChanged()`

```
get
{
    return _display;
}
set
{
    var parsed = Decimal.Parse(value);
    _display = parsed.ToString("F2");
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

The real reason why Blazor does not re-render is: it is try to save rebuilding HTML. Since Blazor knows that you bound property to `input` it believe that no need to trigger re-rendering after setting property.

The update work:

1. User enter text '5' and press Tab
2. Html `onchange` event was generated
3. Blazor capture `onchange` even and call `amount.Display = "5";`
4. Done.

Comment: I've tried this, but it doesn't work. This suggestion also wouldn't explain the discrepancy I describe: why does the input field update inconsistently?

Comment: Update the workflow, how Blazor change property. it is no reason for it to re-render the UI after value is changed, so very likely it is not updated.

Comment: Definitely does not work. -- Btw it's bound to a string not a decimal value.  For all intents and purposes the value DID change, it was previously "2.00" and now it's just "2". -- there should be no difference between changing from "2.00" and "1", both are different string values.

Comment: StateHasChanged works for some handlers but not onchange :/

Comment: The reason why StateHasChanged doesn't work is because it's merely a *suggestion* to your component. Ultimately, the component itself will decide if it needs to re-render or not, and it does this by checking the properties of its model (or the model itself if it's a primitive). It doesn't care that ou called `ToString()` or that that output is now different.

If you need a workaround, you can override the `ShouldRender()` method, but that comes with its own set of issues.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't ideal, but it works. We can create an `ElementReference` in Blazor then pass that along to JavaScript with the value we want to update. This example uses collocated JavaScript files.

First we need to define our `View.razor`:

```
@using Microsoft.JSInterop;
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

<input @ref="_amountDisplayRef"></input>

@code {

    // Create an element reference to the input file and our collocated JavaScript

    ElementReference _amountDisplayRef;
    IJSObjectReference? _collocatedJs;

    // Define our render loop

    PeriodicTimer? _renderTimer;
    async void RenderLoop()
    {
        _renderTimer ??= new(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        while(await _renderTimer.WaitForNextTickAsync())
        {

            // Call our collocated JavaScript with the function `setElementValue`, our element rference and the value we want to set

            if (_collocatedJs != null)
            {    
                await _collocatedJs.InvokeVoidAsync("setElementValue", _amountDisplayRef, DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToString("o"));
            }
        }
    }

    // Get our collocated JavaScript and start our render loop

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
        if(firstRender)
        {
            _collocatedJs = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./_content/Blazor.Client.Shared/Components/View.razor.js");
            RenderLoop();
        }
    }

    // Dispose the timer

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _renderTimer?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Then we can define our collocated JavaScript `View.razor.js`:

```
export function setElementValue(elementReference, value) {
    elementReference.value = value;
}
```